# Как установить драйвер видео?

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер, radeon

Как установить на Debian 6, драйвер видеокарты ATI Radeon HD 2600 и настроить берил?

Answer (score 2):

> Установить:

```
aptitude install xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd
```

есть ещё xserver-xorg-video-radeon и xserver-xorg-video-ati, можно попробовать, что лучше подойдёт для видеокарты.

> Настроить берил..

думаю поможет:

```
aptitude search compiz
```

и гугл, если берил заменить на compiz или compiz-fusion.